# Header width not extending to match sibling when sibling overflows

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

My current code display a container with a header and a content `div`. I want the header to extend to match the sibling width when the sibling overflows. I thought the `flex-1` would allow for that, but it doesn't. What can I do?

```
<div class="flex w-[500px] flex-col overflow-x-auto bg-red-300">
  <h1 class="flex-1 bg-orange-300">Header</h1>
  <div class="h-96 w-[750px] bg-green-300">Content</div>
</div>
```

[Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/aUfWpZtSJI)

Comment: Can you post a tailwind play with the desired state for "when the sibling overflows"? how does it should look like. Because I could not get what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The child component will extend to have the same width as the parent, so you have two options here to achieve the result you want:

(i) Add a div that will encapsulate Header and Content:

```html
<div class="w-[500px] overflow-x-auto bg-red-300">
  <div class="w-[750px]">
    <h1 class="bg-orange-300">Header</h1>
    <div class="h-96 bg-green-300">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(ii) Set the same width to both Header and Content (you can use a variable for this):

```html
<div class="w-[500px] overflow-x-auto bg-red-300">
  <h1 class="w-[750px] bg-orange-300">Header</h1>
  <div class="h-96 w-[750px] bg-green-300">Content</div>
</div>
```

You don't need flexbox for this.